# How to get currently opened article vote / rating value

Tags: template-override, com-content

I want to display the article rating number in my template  'com_content/article' override. How can I get the value of rating_sum and rating_count of the opened article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please avoid pushing pure queries. Do it like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->
    select('rating_sum')->
    from('#__content_rating')->
    where('content_id='.(int)$this->item->id);
$db->setQuery($query) ;
$rating = $db->loadResult();
```

This will make your code more portable.

Answer (score 0):

No problem found it

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$id = $this->item->id;
$sql = 'SELECT rating_sum FROM #__content_rating WHERE content_id='.$id;
$db->setQuery($sql) ;
$rating = $db->loadResult();
```